# printing hash elements to file

Tags: ruby, file, hash, printing

hello guys im trying to print the elements of hash into a file using `table-print` yet this `tp` would print each key in a column but what i want is to have all the `keys` in one column  named `words` and all the values in an other column named `num`.

so here what i wrote till now:

```
class Xclass
  require 'table_print'
  attr_accessor :dic

  def initialize()
    @dic = { apple: 1, water: 2 , orange: 3 }
  end
  def getkeys
    dic.keys.sort.each do |key|
      return key
    end
  end
  def getvalue
    dic.values.sort.each do |value|
      return value
    end
  end
  def nice

    f = File.open("users.txt", "w")
    tp.set :io, f
    #tp [dic], words:getkeys , num:getvalue #just a helpless try generate the same error but `merge' for :apple:Symbol
    tp [dic], words:dic.keys  , num:dic.values
  end
end

Xclass.new().nice()
```

yet this code generate the following error:

```
         10: from table.rb:27:in `<main>'
     9: from table.rb:23:in `nice'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print.rb:73:in `tp'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print.rb:34:in `table_print'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print.rb:65:in `columns'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print.rb:65:in `new'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print/config_resolver.rb:13:in `initialize'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print/config_resolver.rb:41:in `process_option_set'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print/config_resolver.rb:41:in `collect'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print/config_resolver.rb:41:in `block in process_option_set'
     /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/table_print-1.5.6/lib/table_print/config_resolver.rb:66:in `option_to_column': undefined method `merge' for [:apple, :water, :orange]:Array
```

## possible solution but costly

i could write something like this but

```
  def nicePrintToFile(f)
    i=0
    product = Struct.new(:words,:occurances)
    products=Array.new(self.hash.size)
    self.hash.keys.sort.each do |key|
      products[i+=1]=product.new(key, self.hash[key])
    end
    tp.set :io, f
    tp products
  end
```

so is there any solution that doesn't require extra data because this is just a prototype and I'm planning to work with big files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table_print` doesn't really work on individual hashes, but it'll work well on an array of hashes.  For example:

```
> tp [{foo: "foo1", bar: "bar1"}, {foo: "foo2", bar: "bar2"}]
FOO  | BAR
-----|-----
foo1 | bar1
foo2 | bar2
```

In this example, the keys are across the top.  If you want to print a hash with the keys down the side, you do need to transpose it into an array somehow.  For example:

```
> dic = { apple: 1, water: 2 , orange: 3 }
> tp dic.to_a.map{|k,v| {word: k, num: v}}
WORD   | NUM
-------|----
apple  | 1
water  | 2
orange | 3
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. :) but would you please tell me if there is any possibility i could add one column to the right of the num column. 
because trying the `tp dict.to_a.map{|k,v|{word:k, num:v}}, :numberInpercent()` didn't work. and again im very thankful for your help :)

Comment: You can add whatever columns you want.  As long as you're printing an array of hashes, whatever columns you put in the hash will be printed, so if you have more data you can just include it in the hashes.

Comment: However, if your new column is derived from existing data, you can calculate the new column on the fly: `tp dic.to_a.map{|k,v| {word: k, num: v}}, include: {pct: lambda{|row| row[:num] / 100.0}}`